# CKEditor Drag Image just reloads the editor with no image in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to use the upload image plugin of ckeditor (4.7 version) without any luck. The image gets uploaded alright, but after upload finishes the editor flashes and apparently reloads with no image in it.

Server side code is like this:

```
try
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase uploads = HttpContext.Request.Files["upload"];
            string file = uploads.FileName;
            string ruta = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + file);
            uploads.SaveAs(ruta);
            var exito = new
            {
                uploaded = 1,
                fileName = file,
                url = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://localhost:7742/App_Data/" + file),
            };
            return Json(exito, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

And the editor is configured like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.config.language = 'es';
    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'uploadimage';
    CKEDITOR.config.imageUploadUrl = '/Home/UploadImages';
    CKEDITOR.replace("editorNosotros");
</script>
```

I know I'm not providing many details but I'm following ckeditor's documentation ([here](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_file_upload)) and I'm not finding any information about this behavior (most of what I've googled refers to previous versions of ckeditor). 
I also tried changing the url to just `/App_Data/" + file` but nothing seems to work. I'm not sure if the editor is actually reloading or what's actually happening.

Ok, thanks to HMR comments things are getting interesting. I added the following code because anything else returned a 404 error as the path to the image was incorrect:

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://localhost:7742");
            Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "App_Data/" + file);
            var exito = new
            {
                uploaded = 1,
                fileName = file,
                url = myUri.PathAndQuery
            };
```

I also had to add a configuration in the web config:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="App_Data" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Now all the requests for the image return Ok, but I cannot see the json response of my controller action and still the editor reloads with no image in it.

Any comment will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you open the developer tools and go to the network tab could you please add to your question what the response of the post to server looks like? for example, I get `{
  "fileName": "my file.png",
  "uploaded": 1,
  "url": "/userfiles/files/my%20file.png"
}` from https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html (second editor)

Comment: @HMR Actually that's what's weird. I cant see the request to the route that is configured as imageUploadUrl. It seems that the whole page gets replaced before  I get a chance to see that route

Comment: Can you see the request in the example: https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/fileupload.html (second editor)? If you can than it's not a browser issue, you can check "preserve log" and see what's going on before the window reloads.

Comment: @HMR I edited my question and my code, I get Ok for all requests now, but still no luck

Comment: If you can see the 200 status in the network tab (chrome dev tools) then clicking on the request should get you the details (usually headers tab) you should see the response content in preview or response tab. Maybe the content type is not set correctly (application/json)

Comment: @HMR Sorry yo bother everyone with an old question because I had thought the situation was solved. Once I saw the editor behaving, but later on the editor keeps reloading without showing the image, the response status is still Ok. And I can see the call for the image url is right even when I copy the url and paste it in the adress bar, but still no luck